# How to create an Exchange mailbox?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to create an Exchange mailbox in C#. The following code doesn't produce an error, but it also doesn't appear to create a mailbox as I would expect:

```
private void buttonCreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean Success = CreateUser(textBoxFirstName.Text, textBoxLastName.Text,
        textBoxAlias.Text, textBoxPassword.Text,
        comboBoxDomain.SelectedItem.ToString(),
        comboBoxOrganizationalUnit.SelectedItem.ToString());

    if (Success)
    {
        labelStatus.Text = "User Created";
    }
    else
    {
        labelStatus.Text = "There Is Some Error";
    }
        
}

public Boolean CreateUser(string FirstName, string LastName, string Alias,
    string PassWord, string DomainName, string OrganizationalUnit)
{
    string Name = FirstName + " " + LastName;
    string PrincipalName = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@" + DomainName;

    Boolean success = false;
    RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    SecureString spassword = new SecureString();
    spassword.Clear();

    foreach (char c in PassWord)
    {
        spassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
    PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn(
        "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapInException);
    Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
    myRunSpace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

    Command myCommand = new Command("New-MailBox");
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", Name);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("Alias", Alias);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserPrincipalName", PrincipalName);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("Confirm", true);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("SamAccountName", Alias);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("FirstName", FirstName);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("LastName", LastName);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("Password", spassword);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("ResetPasswordOnNextLogon", false);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("OrganizationalUnit", OrganizationalUnit);
    pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
    pipeLine.Invoke();
    myRunSpace.Dispose();
  
    success = true;

    return success;
}
```

I don't get an error, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**Update**

I am using Web Service For this.If I run same code with windows application it works,But not with WebService? should I make any change in Exchange Server? Though I can Get information of MailBox with Get-MailBox but New-MailBox not Creating User.

Comment: Does the POSH command you're building do what you expect?

Comment: @M.Babcock user is not added in mailbox

Comment: Work out the details of the POSH command manually before trying to dynamically building it with API's that complicate the problem.

Comment: I try this with POSH command and without any problem user is added but not Programatically

Comment: You should be passing in a secured string. There is little point in building a secured string from a normal string (which is why there isn't a constructor to do it)

Comment: How can I fix this error? The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010' is not installed on this machine. Do I need to install the Exchange Server Tools on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the solution for this .I change permission leval of inproxy.dll and whooooo its working great ...

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this very issue for a few days (I knew nothing about C# as a language before this week). Anyway, for anyone like me, looking to implement this, but struggling, here is an example that works for me:

We use Exchange2010, and I can run this from a machine that doesn't have the exchange tools installed.

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Remoting;
using System.Management.Automation.Host;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands;

static string createmailbox(string name, string alias, string email, string database, string UPN)
        {

            SecureString spassword = new SecureString();
            string PassWord = "<set default password here or read in input from form>";
            spassword.Clear();

            foreach (char c in PassWord)
            {
                spassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            string orgunit = "<define the OU here if you always use the same one, alternatively, add as parameter in function call>";
            string dc = "<similarly, add DC here if needed, or call  from function>";
            PSCredential newCred = (PSCredential)null;
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("<put in CAS server FQDN here>/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"),
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", newCred);
            connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

            PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("New-Mailbox");
            command.AddParameter("-Name", name);
            command.AddParameter("-Alias", alias);
            command.AddParameter("-UserPrincipalName", email);
            command.AddParameter("-PrimarySMTPAddress", email);
            command.AddParameter("-Password",spassword);
            // (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "P4ssw0rd" -Force)
            command.AddParameter("-Database", database);
            command.AddParameter("-OrganizationalUnit", orgunit);
 //           command.AddParameter("-Email", email);
            command.AddParameter("-DomainController", dc);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            try
            {
                runspace.Open();
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
                return results.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string er = ex.InnerException.ToString();

            }
            finally
            {
                runspace.Dispose();
                runspace = null;

                powershell.Dispose();
                powershell = null;

            }
        }
```

My use case is via a WPF form, so the parameters are populated from text boxes on the form. I've set things like the password (we have a default password for shared mailboxes and the user account is disabled), the OU and the domain controller as static text, but they could be called via variables just as easily.